# How to integrate USPS DelivConfirmCertifyV4Request API to print label into our web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, usps

I am working in ASP.Net with C# and i am new to Integrate USPS. so any one please tell me how to integrate USPS in my web site. here i am using this sample. it always return error :

Authorization failure. DeliveryConfirmationV4 is not a valid API name for this protocol.

http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=DeliveryConfirmationV4&XML=" + xml + "";

Answer (score 0):

Their [documentation](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/usps-tracking-v3-3.htm) shows that the API parameter should be set up like so:

```
?API=DeliveryConfirmationV4.0Request
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get  authorization from USPS. same error i was facing i had contacted customer care then they enabled for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong URL.  The URL is https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll

Also be careful with the API name - it's a bit confusing.  The API `DelivConfirmCertifyV4` (used in the question title) is a *test* API.  The production API is `DeliveryConfirmationV4`.

Here's an example with some code that works that does this: [USPS API - After creating labels retrieving Tracking Number C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355950/usps-api-after-creating-labels-retrieving-tracking-number-c-sharp/46932495#46932495)

Comment: Thanks for helping me on this, it worked form me, appreciate for your help

Answer (score -1):

The solution to your problem is the same on this stackoverflow question-
[How to remove 'SAMPLE DO NOT MAIL' from USPS shipping API image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009078/how-to-remove-sample-do-not-mail-from-usps-shipping-api-image)

And you can find the steps to get this done from my answer on that question or by directly following this link- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27936025/3748701