# I'm try to implement UPSP Label Generating

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I am tryin to implement `UPSP` label generating but i am getting this error.

`**API Authorization failure. DelivConfirmCertifyV3.0Request is not a valid API name for this protocol.**`

if i test on browser, it's working fine

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=%3CAddressValidateRequest%20USERID=%22Testuserid%22%3E%3CAddress%20ID=%221%22%3E%3CAddress1%3E%3C/Address1%3E%3CAddress2%3E10051+Orr+%26amp%3b+Day+Rd%3C/Address2%3E%3CCity%3Esanta+fe+springs%3C/City%3E%3CState%3Eca%3C/State%3E%3CZip5%3E90670%3C/Zip5%3E%3CZip4%3E%3C/Zip4%3E%3C/Address%3E%3C/AddressValidateRequest%3E
```

Anyone know about this problem...

Code Is below:

```
  public Package GetDeliveryConfirmationLabel(Package package)
        {
            string labeldate = package.ShipDate.ToShortDateString();
            if (package.ShipDate.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
                labeldate = "";
            string url = "?API=DelivConfirmCertifyV3.0Request&XML=<DelivConfirmCertifyV3.0Request.0Request USERID=\"{0}\"><Option>{1}</Option><ImageParameters></ImageParameters><FromName>{2}</FromName><FromFirm>{3}</FromFirm><FromAddress1>{4}</FromAddress1><FromAddress2>{5}</FromAddress2><FromCity>{6}</FromCity><FromState>{7}</FromState><FromZip5>{8}</FromZip5><FromZip4>{9}</FromZip4><ToName>{10}</ToName><ToFirm>{11}</ToFirm><ToAddress1>{12}</ToAddress1><ToAddress2>{13}</ToAddress2><ToCity>{14}</ToCity><ToState>{15}</ToState><ToZip5>{16}</ToZip5><ToZip4>{17}</ToZip4><WeightInOunces>{18}</WeightInOunces><ServiceType>{19}</ServiceType><POZipCode>{20}</POZipCode><ImageType>{21}</ImageType><LabelDate>{22}</LabelDate><CustomerRefNo>{23}</CustomerRefNo><AddressServiceRequested>{24}</AddressServiceRequested><SenderName>{25}</SenderName><SenderEMail>{26}</SenderEMail><RecipientName>{27}</RecipientName><RecipientEMail>{28}</RecipientEMail></DelivConfirmCertifyV3.0Request.0Request>";
            url = GetURL() + url;
            //url = String.Format(url,this._userid, (int)package.LabelType, package.FromAddress.Contact, package.FromAddress.FirmName, package.FromAddress.Address1, package.FromAddress.Address2, package.FromAddress.City, package.FromAddress.State, package.FromAddress.Zip, package.FromAddress.ZipPlus4, package.ToAddress.Contact, package.ToAddress.FirmName, package.ToAddress.Address1, package.ToAddress.Address2, package.ToAddress.City, package.ToAddress.State, package.ToAddress.Zip, package.ToAddress.ZipPlus4, package.WeightInOunces.ToString(), package.ServiceType.ToString().Replace("_", " "), package.OriginZipcode, package.LabelImageType.ToString(), labeldate, package.ReferenceNumber, package.AddressServiceRequested.ToString(),  package.FromAddress.Contact, package.FromAddress.ContactEmail, package.ToAddress.Contact, package.ToAddress.ContactEmail);
            url = String.Format(url, this._userid, (int)package.LabelType, package.FromAddress.Contact, package.FromAddress.FirmName, package.FromAddress.Address1, package.FromAddress.Address2, package.FromAddress.City, package.FromAddress.State, package.FromAddress.Zip, package.FromAddress.ZipPlus4, package.ToAddress.Contact, package.ToAddress.FirmName, package.ToAddress.Address1, package.ToAddress.Address2, package.ToAddress.City, package.ToAddress.State, package.ToAddress.Zip, package.ToAddress.ZipPlus4, package.WeightInOunces.ToString(), package.ServiceType.ToString().Replace("_", " "), package.OriginZipcode, package.LabelImageType.ToString(), labeldate, package.ReferenceNumber, package.AddressServiceRequested.ToString(), "", "", "", "");
            string xml = web.DownloadString(url);
            if (xml.Contains("<Error>"))
            {
                int idx1 = xml.IndexOf("<Description>") + 13;
                int idx2 = xml.IndexOf("</Description>");
                int l = xml.Length;
                string errDesc = xml.Substring(idx1, idx2 - idx1);
                throw new USPSManagerException(errDesc);
            }
            int i1 = xml.IndexOf("<DeliveryConfirmationLabel>") + 27;
            int i2 = xml.IndexOf("</DeliveryConfirmationLabel>");
            package.ShippingLabel = StringToUTF8ByteArray(xml.Substring(i1, i2 - i1));
            return package;
        }
```

I get the error on

```
int i1 = xml.IndexOf("<DeliveryConfirmationLabel>") + 27;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is the same on this stackoverflow question- [How to remove 'SAMPLE DO NOT MAIL' from USPS shipping API image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009078/how-to-remove-sample-do-not-mail-from-usps-shipping-api-image)

And you can find the steps to get this done from my answer on that question or by directly following this link- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27936025/3748701

USPS returns the Label in Base64 string you'd be required to convert that into an image. In my application i was required to provide the image as downloadable file, so I have returned the file result from the controller-action. Below is the action which gets the Base64 string label from DB, converts it into image and provides as downloadable file-

```
public ActionResult GetReturnShippingLabel(int orderId, bool showFull)
        {
            string shippingLabel = new OrderRepository().GetOrderReturnShippingLabel(orderId);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(shippingLabel))
            {
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(shippingLabel);
                Image image = null;
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
                image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                if (!showFull)
                    image = image.GetThumbnailImage(326, 570, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
                byte[] imgArray = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
                return File(imgArray.ToArray(), "image/gif");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: wht is the actual it's error mean.I'm already read this.but dn't get solution

Comment: the main issue is that you have to confirm that the api is not in test mode and is in production mode.

Comment: innomanik my code is working fine .Now i need to print the label.Do you have any idea?

Comment: @testtetst please see my updated answer i have provided the code which converts the label string into image and then you can use that image for printing, please mark as answer if this helps you and solves your problem